# AttributeError - 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'exclude'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using raw query because I wanted select unique rows based on single distinct column - Django

```
context['reports'] =  TimesheetEntry.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM timesheet_entry t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT timesheet_users_id, MAX(id) AS latest_id FROM timesheet_entry GROUP BY timesheet_users_id ) t2 ON t1.timesheet_users_id = t2.timesheet_users_id AND t1.id = t2.latest_id WHERE timesheet_is_running=False')
context['reports'] = context['reports'].exclude(pk=36)
```

It is giving me error -

`AttributeError - 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'exclude'`

How can i exclude? Or How to Convert above `RawQuerySet` to `QuerySet`

Comment: if you use `raw` why can't you add the exclusion in your raw SQL? Also if you want help with making this a normal QuerySet, show us your model and explain what kind of result you want so we don't have to decipher the SQL.

Comment: @Shakil `RawQuerySet` doesn't have an attribute `objects` so that's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

you should add another clause directly into your raw query.

something like:

```
context['reports'] =  TimesheetEntry.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM timesheet_entry t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT timesheet_users_id, MAX(id) AS latest_id FROM timesheet_entry GROUP BY timesheet_users_id ) t2 ON t1.timesheet_users_id = t2.timesheet_users_id AND t1.id = t2.latest_id WHERE timesheet_is_running=False 
AND t1.id <> 36')
```